# For which spaces the set of all vectors satisfying $|x-y|=|x+y|$ always forms subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I'm looking for an elementary condition, which imposed on a norm $|\cdot|$ of space $X$ would imply that for every $x\in X$ the set:
$$\mathcal{T}(x)=\{y\in X\big||x-y|=|x+y|\}$$
formed linear subspace of $X$.
Note that every Euclidean space of dimension at least 2 (with standard norm) satisfy it (In $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\mathcal{T}(x)$ is set of all vectors perpendicular to $x$), but for example $C([0,1])$ space with supremum norm does not (To see that let $f(x)=4-x,~g(x)=x$ then $f\in \mathcal{T}(g),~\frac{f}{2}\notin \mathcal{T}(g)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a normed space satisfying the parallelogram identity

$|x-y|^2+|x+y|^2=2(|x|^2+|y|^2)$

so if $X$ is essentially a pre hilbert space.

Since then

$|x+y|=|x-y|$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $|x+y|^2=|x-y|^2$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $2|x+y|^2=2(|x|^2+|y|^2)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\langle x,y\rangle=0$

Therefore $\mathcal{T}(x)=\lbrace x\rbrace^\perp$ which is a closed linear subspace.

Comment: Here $\langle x,y\rangle:=\frac{1}{4}(|x+y|-|x-y|)$ if $X$ is a $\mathbb{R}$ vector space or $\langle x,y\rangle:=\frac{1}{4}[|x+y|^2-|x-y|^2+i (|x+iy|^2-|x-iy|^2)]$ in case of a $\mathbb{C}$ vector space.